# Delete used range from every worksheet in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

i have this test dataset:

[image: dataset]

i have it on multiple sheets, but its always different range - more columns, more rows etc. Beneath this "header" are always some blank rows.

I would like to loop throug all sheets and select this header using End(xlDown) and End(xlToRight).

I am trying to do this with the following code:

```
    Sub WorksheetLoop()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Set rng = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
            rng.Delete
    Next ws

End Sub
```

This macro deletes everything on first worksheet and nothing happens on any other sheet.

I tried using ws.rng but then i get an object error.

Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong?

I am studying some VBA material and trying to make changes, but i always end up with an error.

Thanks

Comment: `Set rng = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))` or neater is `Set rng = ws.Range("A1").currentregion`.

Comment: oh wow, why is the solution always so easy :( i was adding prefix in front of first Range not the second. So i always need to put worksheet reference in front of every range in statement. Another note taken, thank you :)

Comment: @Raymond_90 - this is a great use case for a `With ws...End With` block.

Comment: You do, not doing so is a common reason for questions here so you are ahead of the curve.

Comment: @BigBen thank you, i will look into it, SJR thank you again, can i somehow flag your comment as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is very common.

You must add a sheet reference to every instance of `Range` (and `Cells`) as otherwise your range can be straddling two sheets (the specified one and the active sheet, which is implied in the absence of anything else), which causes an error.

```
Set rng = ws.Range("A1", ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
```

In this particular case, you could also consider this variation:

```
Set rng = ws.Range("A1").currentregion
```

[CurrentRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion).